# Is there any way to achieve the "Message Seen" function with Strophe on Ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, strophe

I am just wondering is there a Strophe plugin for Message delivery receipt that works with Ejabberd??

I am trying to understand how the message delivery receipt works, is there any document/plugin from Strophe?

Answer (score 5):

To acheive [Message Delivery Receipt](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html), you can use the [strophe.receipts.js](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugin-receipts) plugin. Using this the sender of a message can request some notification that the message has been delivered to a client controlled by the intended recipient.

Using this receipts plugin you can't achieve the "Message Seen" feature. To do that, you have to use the XEP extension [XEP-0333 Chat Markers](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0333.html) protocol. As of now, there is no any Strophe plugin to implement this feature.

To achieve the "Message Seen" feature, you can check the [XEP-0085 Chat State Notification](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) XEP extension protocol. StropheJs supports this with [strophe.chatstates.js](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/chatstates/strophe.chatstates.js) plugin. Moreover by using Chat State Notifications you could infer that a message has been read by the recipient, if they become active at any point after the message has been delivered.

Comment: But if the sender wasnt online when the message was read by the receiver, then the chatstates plugin wouldnt be able to tell? Only when both users are online then the chatstates works?

Comment: @John when the user is offline , first thing the message will not be delivered. So no  recipient can read the undelivered message. When recipient come back online, then message delivered. Later when he opens that message we can say that the recipient is active for that chat and we can mark that message as "Seen".

Comment: @John If sender wants to send a message, definitely he need to come online. So recipient might be offline but sender can't be.

Comment: I understand, but if the sender comes online - sends a message, then goes offline, and the recipient comes online read the message, then goes offline. And the sender gets online after the message was read. The chatstates plugin won't be able to detect that tho right?

Comment: @John It will detect. The chatstate works when recipient is in active state for that chat. If the recipient reads the message when sender is offline then chatstate works like its behaviour. When sender come back online, then it will sync up the chatstate for the message and notifies the sender that the message has been read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88558/discussion-between-yashwanth-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

From the Strophe plugin code, I do not think the receipt plugin allows directly to support the "Message Seen" feature. From what I understand it does support the reliability part and keep the unacked message in queue. However, the purpose is only to resend the message in case it is not acked after a while.

https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/receipts/strophe.receipts.js

I am afraid that you need custom code to implement that feature in Javascript on top of the XMPP protocol feature.

Comment: Hi Sorry i had been sick for a week or so, i took a look at the receipt and chatstate plugin then i had a thought; i was thinking would it be possible to just use the ping plugin/send messages to create a "seen" function. When i am sending a message, i also send a ping, the ping handler sits inside the chatpage, if it send a pong back, i know its had been seen. As for the when recipient is offline, when the message is sent, when the recipient comes online and have the message read, it can send a "message" as seen. So when the sender is online, it will get the seen message.

Comment: If i do it that way above, then i wont have to add in the receipt and chatstate plugin, but using the on_message and ping that i am already using - i am assuming, so it reduces the code that it has to load and run.